# Enable the current location panel in QField

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qfield

How can the current location pannel be enabled within QField? (see picture below)

[image]

Comment: What is the connection to QGIS in this question?

Comment: All projects using QField must be set up in QGIS. Perhaps this option is enabled/disabled when setting up the project in QGIS.

Comment: Short press vs long press https://qfield.org/docs/lt/fieldwork/gps.html